# selenium find elements does not refresh with new page elements

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm crawling several profiles and want to go through several pages from the search results in linkedin.

My code is as follows:

```
for search in search_list:
    driver.get(search)
    time.sleep(30)
    names_searched = []

    time.sleep(10)

    for pages in range(5,16):
        time.sleep(30)
        driver.refresh()
        all_users = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='search-results-container']//a[contains(@href,'miniProfileUrn')][contains(@class,'scale-down')]")

        for user in all_users:
            profile_links = user.get_attribute('href')
            names_searched.append(profile_links)
        go_profile(names_searched, counter, driver)
        scroll(driver)
        curr_page = '{}{}{}'.format(search, page_counter, pages)
        driver.get(curr_page)
    counter += 1
```

The code works and does not throw a stale element error or complain that it cannot find the elements. However, when I go back to for pages in range for loop, it goes through the correct page number (ie. page 2 of search results) but `all_users` does not get refreshed with the actual profiles from that page and instead goes through the same profiles from the original url.

I thought waiting for the page to fully load (adding the sleep) and refreshing the page (driver.refresh()) would help selenium to find all elements but so far has not worked.

What am I missing?

Comment: You need to post a [mcve]. There's a lot of methods and variables referenced in your posted code that isn't included. We can't figure this all out unless we see something we can run start to finish.

Comment: Also, all those random sleeps and page refreshes aren't helping, they're just slowing down your script. If you need to wait, use a proper `WebDriverWait`. Are you sure the URL generated in `curr_page` is correct and the proper page? print that out and verify that it's correct.